# Tips for golfing in uBasic

Tags: code-golf, tips, basic

UBASIC is a freeware [basic](/questions/tagged/basic) interpreter written by Yuji Kida at Rikkyo University in Japan, specialized for mathematical computing. It is considered to be a "ready-to-run" language that and is capable of running on DOS and Windows.

What general tips do you have for golfing in uBasic? Any ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to uBasic. Please post one tip per answer.

> Some helpful links
>
> [uBasic Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBASIC)
>
> [Try it Online](https://tio.run/#uBASIC)

Answer (score 1):

## Use `?` in place of `Print`

Instead of using the `Print` command, `?` may be used, as is the case in many BASIC languages - this means that the most simplest uBASIC `Hello, World!` program is as follows

```vb
0?"Hello, World!"
```

Rather than

```vb
10 Print "Hello, World!"
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwF7JIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUen/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid Whitespace in `For` and Like statements

Whitespace between `For` and a variable name is not necessary in uBASIC meaning that a `For` loop may be condensed from

```
0 For t = 1 To 2
1 ?t
2 Next t
```

to

```
0Fort=1To2
1?t
1Nextt
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/SCHT1lAhJF/B0IDL0D7TmsvIL7WiRCHz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## Execute multiple commands on a single line with `:`

uBasic allows for the execution of many commands on a single line with the use of `:` over a new line and new line number.

This means that this (50 Bytes)

```
0Fori=0To10
1Forj=1To9Step3
2?i*10+j
3Nextj
4Nexti
```

May be condensed to this (46 Bytes)

```
0Fori=0To10:Forj=1To9Step3:?i*10+j:Nextj:Nexti
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/KNPWICTf0MAKyMyyNQzJtwwuSS0wtrLP1DI00M6y8kutKIGQmf//AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Use `;` to `Print` Without a Newline

Much like is the case in VBA and other BASIC languages, you may add a `;` to the end of a print statement to keep from printing a newline character and continue printing on that line.

Example:

```
0For i=1 To 10
1?i;
2Next i
```

Outputs

```
12345678910
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/SCHT1lAhJF/B0IDL0D7TmsvIL7WiRCHz/38A)

Similarly, `,` may be appended to the end of a print statement to prevent to pad the output right to a width of eight characters (note however, the output number or string must be of a length less than or equal to 6 characters)

Example

```
0?1,"|"
```

Outputs

```
1       |
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwN5QR6lG6f9/AA)